# Does the following relation hold?

Tags: functions, supremum-and-infimum

Suppose $f$ and $g$ are Schwartz functions. Does the following result hold?

$\sup_x|f(x)g(x)|=\sup_x|f(x)|\sup_x|g(x)|$

In general, for what class of functions this is valid ? Or is it that this relation is always true ?

Comment: It certainly isn't always true – have you tried any examples at all? For it to be true, $f$ and $g$ must achieve their sup at the same $x$.

Comment: Are you still here?

Comment: oh yeah !! got just a little busy of late. Will the following example work $f(x)=\exp(-x^2)$ & $g(x)=\exp(-|x|^2)$ ?

Comment: Is it true that one sided inequality holds always ? ie, LHS $\le$ RHS or RHS $\le$LHS

Comment: Say $\sup_x|f|=f(a)$, $\sup_x|g|=g(b)$, and $\sup_x|fg|=f(c)g(c)$. Then $$\sup_x|fg|=f(c)g(c)\le f(a)g(b)=\sup_x|f|\sup_x|g|$$

Comment: yeah thanks !! now I got it !!

Comment: Good. You could write up what you've got, and post it as an answer.